# Как заблокировать временно прокрутку экрана?

Tags: java, android

Если делаю видимым скрытый элемент layout видимым (который в верхней части экрана), при условии когда содержимое не помещается на экран, происходит прокрутка экрана вниз.

Как это запретить (временно), чтобы на экране была видна только верхняя часть?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот нужная для этого строка: `fullparentscrolling.setEnabled(false);` - она блокирует прокрутку как горизонтально, так и вертикально. Так же можно блокировать только односторонние прокрутки:

```
fullparentscrolling.setVerticalFadingEdgeEnabled(false);
fullparentscrolling.setHorizontalFadingEdgeEnabled(false);
```